# Tensorflow Isn't Recoginizing One Hot Encoded Labels

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

I am training my CNN on 10K grayscale images which are resized to 50x50px, with 6 classes using a one hot encoder. When i train the model i get the model from an insanely high loss to down at about 190 (my lowest i could get) and a terrible accuracy of approximately 16%. When i make a prediction using 10 test images i receive a sequence of 10 numbers that are usually the same like [2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ] or [5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5] for example, but this is not always the case, sometimes it can just be a bunch of random numbers.

This is how i am encoding:

```
def load_data(TRAINING_DIR):
    images = []
    labels = []
    directories = [d for d in os.listdir(TRAINING_DIR) 
                if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(TRAINING_DIR, d))]
    # Need to sort these because
    # floyd hum jumbled up the order
    directories = sorted(directories, key=int)

# Traverse through each directory and make a list
# of files names if they end in the PNG format
for d in directories:
    label_directory = os.path.join(TRAINING_DIR, d)
    file_names = [os.path.join(label_directory, f) 
                    for f in os.listdir(label_directory) 
                      if f.endswith(".png")]
    #Traverse through each file, add the image data
    # and label to the 2 lists
    for f in file_names:
        images.append(skimage.data.imread(f))
        labels.append(int(d))

return images, labels

images, labels = load_data(TRAINING_DIR)

images = np.array(images, object)
labels = np.array(labels, object)

# Convert labels into a one hot vector 
labels = pd.get_dummies(labels)

print('imported...')
```

Then when i train the model it appears to be actually training because the loss is decreasing. But when i run an inference on the model, the predicted labels are in no way the same format as the one hot encoded? Here is my Session.

```
def train_network(x):
pred = convolutional_network(x)
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels = y, logits = pred))
train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.085).minimize(loss)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer()) # Initialize all the variables
    saver = tf.train.Saver()

    time_full_start = time.clock()
    print("RUNNING SESSION...")
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):

        epoch_loss = 0
        time_epoch_start = time.clock()
        i = 0
        while i < len(images):
            start = i
            end = i+ batch_size
            train_batch_x = images[start:end]
            train_batch_y = labels[start:end]

            print('Training...')
            op , loss_value = sess.run([train_op, loss], feed_dict={x: train_batch_x, y: train_batch_y})
            epoch_loss += loss_value
            i += batch_size
        print('Epoch : ', epoch+1, ' of ', num_epochs, ' - Loss for epoch: ', epoch_loss)
```

Here is an example of what im talking about. After the model is trained I feed 10 images of the first class, and receive mostly 5's back. Should the model not return something like [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] because thats what it was trained on?

[image]

Here is the jupyter notebook if you want to take a closer look of the code 
https://www.floydhub.com/arse123/projects/cnn-1/8/code/train_edge.ipynb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's happening because of `correct_pred = tf.argmax(pred, 1)`, it's giving you class with the highest probability after the softmax. You can use `predicted = sess.run(pred, feed_dict={x: test_images[0:10]})`. Now, you will get probability of each class for given images For example you might get [.1, .05, .05 , .6, .1, .1] for your 6 classes. You won't get [0,0,0,1,0,0].Now, argmax will give you index corresponding to .6.

Also, add :

`pred_ = tf.nn.softmax(pred)`

```
predicted = sess.run(pred_, feed_dict={x: test_images[0:10]})
```

Comment: I done what you said but the results aren't even legible https://imgur.com/vApqRXd, they float numbers are too small to read. How would i go about fixing this? (also the results in the image are just for one image)

Comment: I have added the required code. Also, the float values are very large. You need softmax to normalize them while prediction.

Comment: Okay i think we a getting somewhere [Here is an image of the results](https://imgur.com/zXe9TD6) , but it predicts different (and incorrect) one hot value's each time for the same images, Do i need to use this softmax function in training and retrain the model?

Comment: You have already used it here:  loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels = y, logits = pred)). I can't say why are you gettin incorrect results without getting into details.